# Is there an invariant measure absolutely continuous wrt to the lebesgue measure for the map f

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ where $f(x)=x/2$ $(1-x)$, and let $\lambda$ be the lebesgue measure on [0,1]. Is there a probability measure $\mu$ that is invariant and absolutely continuous wrt to the lebesgue measure.

I had 2 ideas for possible measures $\mu() = \int_{} \lambda$  and $\mu()=1/ \sum_{=0}^{−1} ^{}_{*}()$, where $f_{}^{∗} \lambda ()=\lambda(^{-}())$ however I am not sure how to actually show these are invariant and absolutely continuous wrt to the lebesgue measure.

Comment: What on earth is an ACIP?

Comment: @Blackbird A measure $\mu$ in M(X,f) is  an absolutely continuous invariant probability measure (i.e. acip) if $\mu$<<Lebesgue. Apologies I didn't realise the abbreviation wasn't commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such measure.  Hint: what happens if you apply f over and over?

Comment: Thanks. As you iterate f you always end up converging to the origin. I thought that, but I wasnt sure why that means there won't be any measure absolutely cts wrt to $\lambda$. Is it because the long term behaviour of the system means the lebesgue measure always converges to zero?

Comment: Right!  Suppose there is such a measure,  then for some $ \epsilon >0 $ we have $ \lambda (0,\epsilon)<0.5$. But then $$1=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda (f^{-n} (0,\epsilon))=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\lambda (0,\epsilon)<0.5$$,  a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks alot. So from what you said I understand that the examples I gave aren't invariant. How can you then conclude that there aren't any invariant measures absolutely continuous wrt to the lebesgue measure?

Comment: @jd123 my previous comment is a proof that there are no absolutely continuous  invariant measures. Note that the union over n of $f^{-n} (0, \epsilon) $ is (0,1).

Comment: Im sorry I dont think I follow, I don't quite see how this means there doesn't exist a (invariant) measure $\mu$ s.t. when $\mu (E)>0$ then $\lambda (E)>0$.

Comment: What confusing me is that it is only the measure $\mu$ that has to be invariant, $\lambda$ isn't invariant in this case?

Comment: Oops I'm sorry,  it should say $ \mu $ instead of $\lambda$ everywhere.